# If I have a table of secondary indexes and a foreign key, are indexes created per unique foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table of secondary indexes and a foreign key, for each unique foreign key in the foreign key index, are there also also secondary indexes automatically created in SQL? I want to select a group of rows based on a foreign key, then do queries based on secondary indexes of those rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "foreign key index tree"?  I am not familiar with that term.  Also, tag only with the database you are using.  MySQL or Postgres, but not both.

Comment: I meant to say just foreign key index because an index is effectively a tree I am  now aware that it's redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically write an SQL query referencing columns and values you want to search for. You don't refer specifically to indexes or foreign key constraints in a query.

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE author = 'Bill Karwin';
```

(No index or foreign key is referenced in this example.)

Indexes are chosen automatically by MySQL's query optimizer. There are ways to override that index choice, but normally you don't need to do that.

A foreign key is a constraint, not a thing you can query. You never refer to a foreign key by name in an SQL query, except when you create or drop that constraint.

Foreign keys automatically constrain the values you can insert, update, or delete in the table. To do this efficiently, there must be an index on the foreign key column. When you create the foreign key constraint, if there is no index it can use, it creates an index automatically. But if there was already an equivalent index, the constraint just uses that one.

---

Re your comments:

I can answer for MySQL. Other implementations may handle indexes differently. You tagged your question with at least two different implementations.

In the example you show:

```
SELECT * FROM Books 
WHERE author = 'AuthorWhoWroteAMillionBooks' 
  AND title='Book8888';
```

If `title` is indexed, first MySQL will narrow down the search by using the index. Suppose this results in 50 books that may or may not be authored by the author you are searching for. This is referred to as the "examined rows".

Then it will search this subset of rows (the examined rows) row-by-row, evaluating the other search term against these rows. This is more expensive than using an index, but at least it's done *after* any index has been used to reduce the set of examined rows.

MySQL knows how to do this regardless of the order of terms in your WHERE clause.

There is no such thing as a second layer of indexes.

You could further optimize this query by using a compound index on the pair of columns in your search.

```
CREATE INDEX author_and_title ON Books (author, title);
```

This will create a single index tree for the pair of values. Then the single index search will reduce the set of examined rows to just those that match both terms of your search conditions.

Comment: Say I have a secondary index on column called Title in the Books table. If I call SELECT * FROM Books WHERE author = 'AuthorWhoWroteAMillionBooks' AND title='Book8888'; with the million rows returned from the first part of the query, will it then do a linear scan on the million rows to find title 'Book8888', or is there an index i can query built for that unique foreign key 'AuthorWhoWroteAMillionBooks' on the column 'Title'.

Comment: I am aware that indexes are automatically chosen by the SQL engine, but does it create this second layer of indexes that I speak of?

Comment: Although I do admit my scenario is quite ridiculous, it probably wouldn't get million rows then do a scan, it probably accesses the Title index first then for each book titled 'Book8888' it comes across if the author matches 'AuthorWhoWroteAMillionBooks'. Yeah. I suppose it seems that second layer of indexes is unnecessary in this scenario. However, it does appear in certain scenarios it would be an extra layer of optimization.

Comment: MySQL does support something called an index merge, where two indexes are searched, and then the intersection of those results becomes the ultimate result of the query. Is that what you mean? Using a compound index as I showed above is better for performance than the index-merge operation. And strangely, MySQL usually uses only one index per table, not the index-merge operation even if both indexes exist.

Comment: For example, a scenario where you would want to find all 100 elements greater where linear scanning would be involved if such second layer of indexes do not exist. For example this query: SELECT * FROM Books WHERE author = 'AuthorWhoWroteAMillionBooks' AND title>'Book8888' LIMIT 100;

Comment: The compound index I described can do that.

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: I see. The compound index is essentially what I'm describing. Thank you. I'll check out your presentation and video. Thanks again